# using jdbctemplate for insert/update

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring simplejdbctemplate for bunch of insert/update based on if/else blocks.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to combine all these operations into one transaction. Currently, if my code breaks (for some reason) then certain inserts are executed and certain are not. I would like the whole thing to fail, if anything fails. Like rollback in SQL.

Is this possible to do with simplejdbctemplate?

The link does not not help me much as I don't understand where I can place `@Transaction`. I am pasting the code below, Where would `@Transaction` annotations go in the code below?

**Update**

code:

```
for (Colors c : colors) {
        if (isColorExistsInOtherDb(c)) {
            if (!isColorExistsAlready(c)) {
                insertIntoColor(c);
                colorId = getMaxColorId();
            }
        else {
            updateColor(c);
            colorId = getColorIdByShade(c);
        }


        for (Shade s : c.getShades()) {
            colorId = colorService.isShadeExistsForColor(colorId, s.getShadeId());
            if (colorId <= 0) {
                colorService.insertIntoColor(s);
                colorId = colorService.getMaxColorId();
            }
            else {
                colorService.updateColor(colorId, c);
            }


                insertMachinePoam(machineId, poamId);
            }
        }
        else {
            //do something else?
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Jdbc Template doesn't control whether you are in a transaction.  This [page](http://springinpractice.com/2008/03/18/annotation-based-transactions-in-spring/) shows an example of using annotations to control transaction settings.

In general, you are making the multiple DAO/jdbc template calls from a service type method.  That method gets annotated for transactions so your jdbc template code can focus on what it is designed to do - access the database.

Comment: I've provided an updated. the link confuses me as to where to put the `@Transaction` annotations

Comment: What class/method is the code you posted in?  The annotation would go there.  If that class isn't already a Spring bean/component, you'd need to make it one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you should use Spring declarative transactions.  It's an aspect, not part of the simple JDBC template.